# How to prevent a subclass from inheriting a field from the superclass using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, oop, inheritance

I have a class A which has a List of a class B. Since the attributes of a A is similar to what a B has, I thought about using inheritance to solve my problem. But I don't want B to have a list to B, and here is my problem. How can I prevent B from inheriting the List of B from the super-class?

The super-class:

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class A
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    protected Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a")
    private List<B> list = new ArrayList<>();

    // other fields that I want to be inherited...
}
```

The subclass:

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@SuperBuilder
public class B extends A
{
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private A a;
}
```

The JSON returned after creating the class A:

```
{
               "id": 1,
               // other fields

               "list": [
                   {
                       "id": 2,
                       // inherited fields

                       "list": [], // I want to prevent this!
                   }
               ],
}
```

And one last thing, the reason why I want to use inheritance in this case instead of creating a B class with its own fields it's because I am using a composite key for solving another problem, and both classes share this composite key.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a dto for class B to specify what you want to show or you can @jsonignore List in class A if you don't need to send A as a JSON